# Importing SQLite tables into Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is there a way to import a large list of SQLite tables into the Azure Mobile Services data creation tool?  I've got an existing iOS app with a large collection of tables and if I have to recreate each one using the tool it's going to take forever.  I was wondering if someone had experience in this area and found a better way.